# How to add name of person like facebook in codeigniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, url

Like in facebook: www.facebook.com/[name_of_user].

For example: www.facebook.com/david.paul

how can we do that in codeigniter? if the first segment of url (name_of_user) is controller name in codeigniter? if name_of_user the same controller it will execute controller instead of name_of_user?

how can we redirect to page not found if name_of_user not available in database?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use .htacces, to get rid of index.php.
After that, you need to create a new route:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'user/checkName';
```

and this route should be the first one. But with this, you should know, that if you have an url such like : `www.example.com/chandra` or `www.example.com/contact`, both of them will go to user controller - checkName method.

And in the methode, after you have the url segment, like chandra, you can seach for it in the database and if you didn't found any, you can create a different view file, or you can use a built in function:

```
show_404('page');
```

And this will use the `application/errors/error_404.php` template.
You can find more information about the 404 page here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html